# $\liminf$ and $\limsup$ for more general case- beyond the sequence set up

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-process

I was reading the book by Ross on Stochastic Processes. In the chapter of renewal process while proving elementary renewal theorem they showed $\liminf_{t\rightarrow \infty} (m(t)/t)=1/\mu$. Here $m(t)=E(N(t))$ where $N(t)$ is the counting process and $t\in(0,\infty)$. 
Now as $t\in(0,\infty)$ $m(t)/t$ is not a sequence. So how can we take $\liminf_{t\rightarrow\infty}$ which is defined on a sequence of real numbers? 
Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $\liminf $ is well defined for a function defined on the set of positive real numbers. For example, if we have a function $f\colon \left[R, +\infty\right)\to \mathbb R$, where $R$ is a positive real numbers, then 
the function 
$$ g\colon\left[R, +\infty\right)\to \mathbb R, g\colon x\mapsto \sup_{t\geqslant x} f(t)  $$
is non-increasing hence $\lim_{ x\to  +\infty}g(x)$ exists and is defined as $\liminf_{  x\to +\infty}f(x)$ in an analogous way as it was defined for sequence.